# How can I apply decorator to a superclass method in a subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-decorators

Say, we have the following situation,

```
class A():
    def something():
        ...
        ...
        ...


class B(A):
    def use_something():
        ...
        ...
        # Now, at this point I want something() to be decorated with a 
        # decorator. But, since it is already defined in base class, 
        # I am not getting how to decorate it here, in the subclass.
        self.something()
        ...
        ...
```

Now, in Class B, I want to use something() from Class A, but I want to apply a decorator to it.
 I cannot decorate it in class A, since there are different decorators that I want to apply at different places. Say, Class C(A) and I want to use something() here as well, with a different decorator.

So, coming back to the original question; how can I apply decorator to a superclass's method in a subclass?

Comment: Why do you need to "apply a decorator" instead of just wrapping the `A.method()` call with subclass-specific code that does whatever the decorator would do?  Please show an example of what you are hoping to do.

Comment: @BrenBarn Can you please throw some light on "wrapping the method" or please guide me towards it, since I am new to these concepts.

Comment: No, I can't, until you show an example of what you want this hypothetical code to do.  It's okay for it to be "fake" code (i.e., code that doesn't really work).  But you need to show a concrete example of what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: @BrenBarn I have updated the OP. Please check.

Comment: `newSomething = decorator(self.something)` and then `newSomething()` – but you could (and should) really just put the logic from the decorator right into the subclass.

Comment: Can we see a concrete example on what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any particular reason why you can't just override `something()`?

```
class A():
    def something(self):
        ...

class B(A):
    def use_something(self):
        ...
        self.something()
        ...

    def something(self):
        # Do "decorator" stuff
        super().something()
        # Do more "decorator" stuff
```

Comment: Hey guys, it's not fair :) Question was about decorators, not using ``super`` method.

Comment: @turkus It was more of an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to be honest. Just because he thinks he needs a decorator doesn't mean a decorator is the correct solution :)

Comment: yeah I know :) But maybe he wanted just to exercise. I don't know. Only he knows :)

Comment: @turkus Still, it's not a good idea to practice playing football with ice skates and a puck.

Comment: I agree, this soulution is better, well, I can say only that: Imagine if you'll go to the shop and want to buy a cake and somebody will give you a bread. You can accept or not, because it wasn't you was asking about.

Comment: Well if you want a cake, bread won't be the answer... A better comparison would be like going to a gas station and asking for motor oil, then they check your car and realize you're just out of gas and tank your car instead of adding motor oil.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (with params and without):

```
def simple_dec(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return 'No way'
    return wrapped


def simple_dec_params(first_param, second_param):
    def dec(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return '{} {}'.format(first_param, second_param)
        return wrapped
    return dec


class A():
    def something(self):
        print 'Something'


class B(A):
    def use_something(self):
        first_param = 'No'
        second_param = 'Way'
        print simple_dec(self.something)()
        print simple_dec_params(first_param, second_param)(self.something)()


b = B()
b.use_something()
```

Comment: What if the simple_dec()  has some parameters?

Comment: Why I got downvote. Please explain. Question was about decorators not using super method.

Comment: @turkus The downvote was there before I posted my answer, so probably for some other reason. Seems like I got a downvote too :P